# how to insert the selected value from DDL to DB by MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

> > hi I have **MVC Razor** application as e catalog and I used drop down-list to bind data from **DB** but the **DDl** bind the same value from **DB** as if I have three categories " x , Y , Z" the **DDL** returned similar values " Z ,Z , Z ".As it have the last value "y" . also I tried to insert the selected value "ID" to DB when user selected the item from **DDL** but I couldn't and it returned false selected value.

```
 public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    private AndriodContext db = new AndriodContext();
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    List<string> category = new List<string>();
    SelectListItem s = new SelectListItem();

    //
    // GET: /Category/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {


        var x = db.Categories.Where(y => y.Active == true).ToList();



        return View(x);

    }



    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var data = db.Categories.ToList().Distinct();
        List<string> x = new List<string>();

        foreach (var t in data)
        {

            s.Text = t.Name;
            s.Value = t.Cat_ID.ToString();

            items.Add(s);

        }

        ViewBag.Parent = items;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Category/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Category category, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {


        var data = db.Categories.ToList().Distinct();
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var t in data)
        {
            SelectListItem s = new SelectListItem();
            s.Text = t.Name;
            s.Value = t.Cat_ID.ToString();
            items.Add(s);
            if (s.Selected)
            { category.Parent_ID = int.Parse(s.Value); }
        }


        db.Categories.Add(category);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }


}
```

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Category", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @data_ajax = "false" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

```
<fieldset>
    <legend></legend>

    <div class="editor-field create-Bt3">

        @Html.DropDownList("Parent", new SelectList(ViewBag.Parent, "Value", "Text"), "- Select Parent -")
    </div>

    <div>
        <p class="create-Bt ">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to import jquery 1.7.1.min.js(DOM) in viewpage :

get the jquery DOM from jquery website(http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/21/jquery-1-7-1-released/).
then in button click (`<input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="GetDropDownValue();"/>`) :

wrote a javascript function :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
  function GetDropDownValue()
   {
     $("#hdnParentId").val($("#Parent").val());
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I had this error "Input string was not in a correct format." here category.Parent_ID = int.Parse(hdnParent);

Comment: thx , it worked but I had new issue as DDL return only the last value as it didn't return all values

Comment: Can you post the full code snippet? in this case I think the value of hdnParent becomes null.
you need to take the hidden field inside the form tag.
Otherwise you can get the value by Request["hdnParent"] inside HttpPost method.

Comment: What do you mean by last value?
Which value you wants in post?

Comment: when I add new category as "x" to DB , the DDL bind only "X" when load the page and it doesn't bind all categories , also it repeated the "x" category equaled the number of categories in DB

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("Parent", new SelectList((IEnumirable)ViewBag.Parent, "Value", "Text"), "- Select Parent -")

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem it is still retrieve only one item and repeat it

Comment: I think it is the problem of your selection from the DB. Please check the query of select and debug the code to get actual output.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to use a model to bind the dropdownlist instead of ViewBag.

If you don't want to use model the you can do one trick.
you put a hidden field(`<input type="hidden" name="hdnParent" id="hdnParentId" />`) in view page and calculate selected value of dropdownlis by simple jquery using : 
`$("#Parent").val();`.

make the dropdownlist :

```
@Html.DropDownList("Parent", new SelectList(ViewBag.Parent, "Value", "Text"), "- Select Parent -",new{ id="Parent" });
```

After that you get a string parameter in HTTPPOST in controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string hdnParent) //hdnParent is the name of dropdownlist
{
    //now you can get the seleced value from "hdnParent".
    //do the stuffs
    return View();
}
```

Comment: how can I use $("#Parent").val();

Comment: you need to import jquery 1.7.1.min.js(DOM) in viewpage :
<script type="script/javascript" src="../1.7.1.min.js" />
get the jquery DOM from jquery website(http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/21/jquery-1-7-1-released/).